# How to set values in a bitset according to a array of floating point values conditions?

Tags: c++, bitset

I have an array of floating point values. The array is converted to binary value array on the basis of a threshold value.
e.g

A = 0.3,1.3,4.4,6.4;

if threshold = 4

A = 0, 0, 1, 1;

Now, I want to convert it to bitset. Is there an easy way to do it.

I am new to programming so sorry if the question is too silly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
float floats[16] = {/*...*/};

std::bitset<16> bits;

for(size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    bits.set(i, floats[i] < 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just convert the array of floats directly to a `std::bitset` when looping over it:

```
std::array<float, N> values = {...};
std::bitset<N> bitset;

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i) {
    bitset[i] = (values[i] > threshold);
}
```